# how to register broadcast receiver for low battery in android?

Tags: android, power-management, android-broadcast

I want to register broadcast for low battery.
If battery status reached at some level I want to get alert...

Please if you have any idea please help me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for [`ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW). You can do this in the manifest with a `<receiver>` element or via `registerReceiver()` from some already-running component of your application.

Comment: As per this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16551151/243709, the documentation is incorrect on this; and instead of ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, using BATTERY_LOW will work, similarly for ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY too

Comment: @SheikhAman: The documentation that you linked to is correct.

Comment: I am right now coding a small app to detect critical low level of batteries, and ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, as said in the documentation, doesn't work. BATTERY_LOW worked, but doesn't seem to be documented. Or might be an Android version related thing too

Comment: @SheikhAman: "BATTERY_LOW worked, but doesn't seem to be documented" -- [`ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW) is a Java `static final` field. It points to a string. That string is `android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW`, as is mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW). It works this way for most of the `ACTION_` values -- for `ACTION_FOO`, the string is `android.intent.action.FOO`.

Comment: Got it, so I am using the constant value (not preferred), which works, but it's constant doesn't. Weird, Will dig more about why. Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe I need some sleep ;-)

Answer (score 4):

For Battery_Status_Low, You could try registering it through a Service for example, like:

```
BatteryReceiver receiver = new BatteryReceiver(); 
IntentFilter inf = new IntentFilter();
inf.addAction("android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW");`
registerReceiver(receiver, inf);
```

Comment: What you actually want to do with battery status ?..You are using Service or Activity ?

Comment: Sample Tutorial for getting [Battery Status](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-battery-level-in-android-using.html)