# How to detect when the Battery's low : Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to close my app when the battery level of the device gets low.
I have added following codes in manifest.

```
 <receiver android:name=".BatteryLevelReceiver" 
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And following code in receiver

```
public class BatteryLevelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "BAttery's dying!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("", "BATTERY LOW!!");
    }
}
```

I am running the app on emulater and changing the battery level using telnet.
It changes the battery level but not showing any toast or logs.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register your receiver in the code, not in the `AndroidManifest` file.

```
registerReceiver(batteryChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(
    Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)); // register in activity or service

public class BatteryChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    int scale = -1;
    int level = -1;
    int voltage = -1;
    int temp = -1;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
        voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
    }
}

unregisterReceiver(batteryChangeReceiver);//unregister in the activity or service
```

Or listen to the battery level with `null` receiver.

```
Intent BATTERYintent = this.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(
        Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
Log.v(null, "LEVEL" + level);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried registerReceiver(myBatteryReceiverLow , new IntentFilter( Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));


But its not working too :(

Comment: Have you cleaned your manifest? And send broadcast action handly ACTION_BATTERY_LOW = "android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW";

Comment: I have cleaned manifest.
But what does send broadcast action handly mean? 
I haven't worked much on broadcasts.. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Read this questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661464/get-battery-level-before-broadcast-receiver-responds-for-intent-action-battery-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584497/what-is-the-difference-between-sendstickybroadcast-and-sendbroadcast-in-android

Comment: I have gone through those questions. Not helping much! :(
Also ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED is a sticky broadcast which cannot be received through components declared in manifests, but only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver()

But where as ACTION_BATTERY_LOW is not sticky broadcast!

Comment: the question is related to when battery gets low, but the example is on changed, irrelevant example.

Answer (score 41):

You can register your receiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, however make sure that the action you are filtering on is

**`android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW`**

and not

**`android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`**

(which you have used in your code).

Answer (score 7):

k3v is correct.

There is actually an error in the documentation.
It specifically says to use `android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`.
But the correct action to put in the manifest is `android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW`
See here: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

(Couldn't vote k3v's answer up, not enough StackOverflow point things...)

UPDATE: I now can and did up-vote k3v's answer :-)

Comment: Well the new document also mentions ACTION_BATTERY_LOW

Comment: Yes, K3v's answer is absolutely correct, that should be the accepted answer

Comment: Just had a discussion with CommonsWare on another question. He rightly points out that with BATTERY_LOW, we start referring the string value of the ACTION_BATTERY_LOW constant. Will need to figure out why the constant doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Register using **context register**. If you are targeting Android 8.0 or higher, you cannot use manifest declared receiver. Paste this code in your main activity to register.

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BatteryLevelReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter =new IntentFilter(BatteryManager.EXTRA_BATTERY_LOW);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

and you are good to go
**PS** the emulator should not be in charging state

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the emulator does not respond to `BATTERY_LOW` and `BATTERY_OKAY` messages. Try on a real Android device.