# Application running in background in android

Tags: android

I want to run an application in background. I want to make an application when battery down to specific level I have to send sms to someone. If my phone is on standby or I am playing game and battery level reach 5% then I have to send sms. I want to Know how to run an application in background??

```
if (BtryLevelOrig==batteryLevel) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "level", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SendSms();
    }
```

Comment: so... what is your question?

Comment: What are you actually asking here? How to register for a notification when the battery level hits a certain level?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to register broadcast receiver for low battery in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513317/how-to-register-broadcast-receiver-for-low-battery-in-android)

Comment: @Michelle actually I want to know how to run an application in background???

Comment: You may have better luck using [an Android developer support site](http://www.andglobe.com) that is in a language that is more comfortable for you.

Comment: @Tarikhelian Do you want your app to do anything other than perform an action (sending an SMS) when the battery is low? Because a broadcast receiver will start your service when it needs to (when the battery is low) without having to run it constantly in the background.

Comment: @Michelle I got the solution below by Libin... i was Confused about the application that run in background. Its "Android service" that perform background task. Thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare.. I can understand English well but sometimes question confuse me about how to ask. Technically terms can understand everybody but if someone don't knows about Technical terms then question become Ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Android Service . If you have to show any user interaction notification, then you can also run your service as Foreground using startForeground

check this link to create your own background custom service. make sure onStartCommand return START_STICKY to run your service continuously .

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html